# Is the Laplace operator dissipative?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Consider the Banach space $C_\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) = \{f \in C(\mathbb{R}^n) \mid \lim_{|x| \to \infty} f(x) = 0\}$ equipped with the supremum norm $||\cdot||_\infty$. My question is wether the Laplace operator $\Delta:C_c^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \to C_\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dissipative, that is, that for all $\lambda>0$ and any $f \in C_c^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ we have 
$$ ||\lambda f - \Delta f||_\infty \geq \lambda ||f||_\infty.$$
Any ideas?

Comment: what properties of the laplace operator on this space do you know about?

Comment: But is there an eigenfunction of $-\Delta$ that has compact support?

Comment: It's a bit cumbersome to calculate, but $f(x):=e^{-1/(1-x^2)}$ is a counter-example with $\lambda = 1$. But again, I think you've got a sign wrong.